# apache beam how to create a schema-aware PCollection

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to use apache beam to read two datasets, and update the first one if a row matching the ID is present in the second dataset. Here is the beam pipeline:

```
class MapDataFrameRow(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        key = element.id
        yield key, element


class MergeTuples(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        key, data = element
        if len(data[1]) > 0:
            yield data[1][0]
        else:
            yield data[0][0]

def run(pipeline_options, state_file, gcs_input_file_path, gcs_output_path):
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        current_state_df = pipeline | 'Read current state CSV' >> read_csv(state_file)
        updates_df = pipeline | 'Read data updates CSV' >> read_csv(gcs_input_file_path)

        # Translate beam dataframe to pcollections
        #  MapDataFrameRow is a DoFn that map the ID as the tuple key.
        cs_pc = to_pcollection(current_state_df, include_indexes=False) | "Map #1 to KV" >> beam.ParDo(MapDataFrameRow())
        nu_pc = to_pcollection(updates_df, include_indexes=False) | "Map #2 to KV" >> beam.ParDo(MapDataFrameRow())

        merged = (
                (cs_pc, nu_pc)
                | 'group by key' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
                | 'keep most recent' >> beam.ParDo(MergeTuples())
                # | 'To rows' >> beam.Map(lambda word: beam.Row(??))
                | beam.ParDo(print)
        )


        df = to_dataframe(merged)
        df.to_csv(gcs_output_path)
```

the code produce the following output:

```
BeamSchema_c46d9a9f_a000_453e_87fe_7f4b372c21a1(id=143, area=130.0, .... )
BeamSchema_c46d9a9f_a000_453e_87fe_7f4b372c21a1(id=144, area=130.0, ... )
BeamSchema_c46d9a9f_a000_453e_87fe_7f4b372c21a1(id=145, area=130.0, ... )
...
```

Unfortunately i am not able to map the merged pcollection into a dataframe, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Could not determine schema for type hint Any. Did you mean to create a schema-aware PCollection? See https://s.apache.org/beam-python-schemas
```

I have tried using  `| 'To rows' >> beam.Map(lambda word: beam.Row(??))` (commented in the code) but I don't want to manually specify all the key values, is there a way to easily map the `BeamSchema` to a dataframe?

**EDIT:**
It appears that the problem is that `to_dataframe(merged)` doesn't like to work with two different `BeamSchema_c46d9a9f_xxxx` and `BeamSchema_3369b0_xxxx` generated by he two `to_pcollection`s. In other words, I am creating two separate pcollections and then I am picking from one source or the other and then trying to create a new dataframe, but because they appear to beam as separate schemas he doesn't like it. What would be a way to merge the two dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see that you applied the transform `beam.ParDo(print)` to produce the `PCollection` `merged`. This means that the `PCollection` you are trying to convert will contain the objects returned by this function. Are you using a custom `print` function that return the original object after printing ?

If above does not resolve the issue, you have to make sure that Beam Python can infer a Schema from the type of objects the `PCollection` represents. For custom types, this can be done by converting the objects to `NamedTuple`s. See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-schemas) for more details.

This should allow `to_dataframe` to properly discover the Schema for type of objects the `PCollection` contains.

Comment: That's actually a very good point. I have removed the `ParDo(print)` and now i get the following error: `TypeError: Could not determine schema for type hint Union[BeamSchema_0d75xxx, BeamSchema_3369b0xxx]. Did you mean to create a schema-aware PCollection?` . Is there a way to not manually create a named tuple and have beam automatically work with objects `apache_beam.typehints.schemas.BeamSchema` without me manually translating the schema into a named tuple?

Comment: This depends on the SDK language. For some types (primitives and some complex types) Beam should already have registered schema inference mechanisms. For other custom types, the link I provided above gives ways to make Beam infer schema for custom types.  For Python SDK you have to either use NamedTuple classes or beam.Row and Select.

Comment: is it possible to do it just with `beam.Row` or `select` is required as well? Because i can get to build rows, but if I need to build the select as well, i need to specify the field names and i don't want to manually specify 100s of fields that will likely change in the future.

Comment: in other words; case 1: `| 'To rows' >> beam.Map(lambda row: beam.Row(**row))` and case 2:
                `| 'To rows' >> beam.Select(id=lambda item: item["id"], area=lambda item: item["area"], year=lambda item: item["year"])` are not equivalent, but I would much rather use the first. However in the second case everything works, but not on the first one unfortunately

Comment: Select transform actually creates a PCollection of Rows [1] so just creating Rows should also be fine. But you have to create a Row object with fields that Beam can identify. I suspect type you put into Row here is a complex type that Beam cannot use to build a schema field for. [1] https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.Select

Comment: What do you suggest? the data is the same, the types are the same, how can i make case 1 work despite they are equivalent methods? or how can I have case 2 work without me manually specifying all the columns names? The data is all floats and ints.

Comment: I don't think the first one will work for you currently since Python SDK currently doesn't have a way to automatically figure out a schema for a complex type (Java SDK can do this based on fields of a POJO, for example). I think this is something that is being planned for Python SDK but don't have an exact ETA.