# why creating a beam dataframe from beam.rows do not work but it does from beam.select

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have simplified my problem with the following two cases:

case 1:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_dataframe

input_file = "gs://bucket/inputfile.parquet"

p = beam.Pipeline()

updates = (p
           | 'Read updates file %s' % (input_file) >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet(input_file)
           | 'To rows' >> beam.Map(lambda row: beam.Row(**row))
           )

df = to_dataframe(updates)
size = df.groupby("year").size()

p.run()
```

case 2:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_dataframe

input_file = "gs://bucket/inputfile.parquet"

p = beam.Pipeline()

updates = (p
           | 'Read updates file %s' % (input_file) >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet(input_file)
           | 'To rows' >> beam.Select(id=lambda item: item["id"], area=lambda item: item["area"], year=lambda item: item["year"])
           )

df = to_dataframe(updates)
size = df.groupby("year").size()

p.run()
```

The only difference is how i create the rows.
Why the second case works but the first one doesn't ???
According to [this](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.Select), they should be equivalent.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666328/apache-beam-how-to-create-a-schema-aware-pcollection ?

(addressed in comments)

Comment: The two questions are different, in the comment we then go off on another point and therefore I thought it would be appropriate to create a separate question for it. Both questions would solve my problem in separate ways, I am happy to have a solution for one or the other.